# upgrade db schema from redmine 1.2.1 to 1.3.0

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, redmine

i have one server with redmine 1.2.1 and webrick webserver. In another new ubuntu server, i've just installed redmine 1.3.0 from the main repo, with apache+passenger. No problem with that.

Then i pg_dumped my old 1.2.1 database and put into my new postgresql for my 1.3.0 redmine. Everything works well except one thing. when i go to watch one of my repos (url like http://myhost.com/projects/myproject/repository/revisions/11806) I get this error

```
ActionView::TemplateError (PGError: ERROR:  relation "changeset_parents" does not exist
```

This means that i didnt upgrade correctly my redmine, is there a way to upgrade this database in my new ubuntu server?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run the Redmine Database migration script?

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will need to be run as a root user in from the /usr/share/redmine directory or whereever you have installed Redmine to.